# How to make icon and Class Wizard work for no-resource applications with resource-only dll?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, mfc, visual-c++

I am working on a MFC project with multiple GUI applications. The objective is to move all the resources from individual projects to a single resource dll.

After some change I have a single resource-only dll project and multiple GUI project. Each GUI project is using the following code to access the resource dll:

```
BOOL CFooApp::InitInstance()
{
    HINSTANCE hRes = NULL;
    hRes = LoadLibrary(_T("Resource.dll"));
    if(hRes) AfxSetResourceHandle(hRes);
    ....
```

So far things work fine except there are two issues:

1. The GUI exe files lose there icons in Windows explorer. Although there are some MFC boilerplate code that load the icon from IDR_MAINFRAME, that only affects the icon in the top 
   of the application window.
2. The Class Wizard won't work anymore. For example I can no longer click on a dialog button in the resource view to add a button handler?

How to solve these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I am using a simple method that almost solved the problem. I just add the central rc file (e.g. Resource.rc in my above example) to each GUI project. Thus: 1) The ClassWizard can be used. 2) Icon are generated for each GUI. 3) Although the GUI project is referencing to a English version rc file, the GUI exe can still load a Resource.dll in other languages. The only draw back is every GUI now has the same icon, presumably the first icon they found in the rc file.

Comment: OK. After all these days with no more answers coming, I will accept my own answer as a less than ideal one.

Answer (score 1):

Explorer grabs it's icon from resources embedded in the exe. If the exe is pulling all its resources from a dll, then Explorer won't find anything. Can you not just add a single icon in the exe?

As for 2, then I think you're stuffed. I've had this issue before when using multiple satellite language resource dlls. The only way to fix it was to keep one (English) set of resources in the exe itself, but this wasn't possible for various reasons specific to us. In the end I just got used to coding without the wizards. :/